# Como tratar registros Null? No banco ou na app? (java & MySQL)

Tags: java, mysql, nullpointerexception, null, void

Estou integrando um banco (MySQL) legado com um novo módulo (Java - esse objeto que dá problema é um bean) que estou desenvolvendo.

Tenho um método que faz um `select` e retorna alguns resultados que, eventualmente, tem alguns dados `null` e isso gera uma exception `Java.lang.NullPointerException`.

Até ai tudo bem, eu entendo esse problema, mas minha dúvida é: eu trato isso no banco, gerando valores vazios para esses registros, ou eu trato isso no meu código, tipo ignorando essas exceptions? E se for o caso de ignorá-las no código, como eu faço isso?

Comment: Na aplicação porque isto é um erro de programação. A não ser que não deveria ter o nulo no banco de dados, e em muitos casos não deveria mesmo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Olá,

Sobre suas dúvidas:

> eu trato isso no banco, gerando valores vazios para esses registros

Não faria isto, a não ser que faça sentido no contexto de negócio da aplicação. Eventualmente fará sentido para um ou outro campo, mas não para todos. Os dados são aqueles e sua aplicação precisa lidar com eles, então o problema continuará.

> ou eu trato isso no meu código, tipo ignorando essas exceptions?

Você tratará no código mas **não ignore as Exceptions**. Quanto menos se envolver com as exceptions, melhor ficará seu código ao meu ver. O que você precisa fazer é mapear quais campos podem vir nulos e preparar sua aplicação para isto.

Por exemplo, se uma coluna `nome` pode vir nula, ao invés de fazer algo como:

```
try {
    nomeEmMaiusculo = nome.toUppercase();
} catch (NullPointerException ex) {
    //ignorar, nome está null
}
```

Faça:

```
if (nome != null) {
    nomeEmMaiusculo = nome.toUppercase();
}
```

Se estiver usando Java 8, você pode melhorar este código usando `Optional`. Assim, quando receber o nome que pode ser nulo, você imediatamente o trata como opcional:

```
Optional<String> optNome = Optional.ofNullable(nome);
```

E para usar o `Optional`:

```
if (optNome.isPresent()) {
    nomeEmMaiusculo = optNome.get().toUppercase();
}
```

Assim fica bem claro para o código seguinte que nome é opcional e o conceito de algo `null`, a partir deste ponto, deixa de ser uma preocupação.

Comment: Pelamor, que resposta excelente!!! Palmas!!! Muito obrigado Dherik, esclareceu bem aqui.